# convert 1d array to 2d array with nan values

Tags: python, numpy, series

suppose I have a series like this

```
S1 = Series([[1 , 2 , 3] , [4 , 5 , 6] , np.nan , [0] , [8 ,9 ]])

0    [1, 2, 3]
1    [4, 5, 6]
2          NaN
3          [0]
4       [8, 9]
```

then I will create a numpy array from this series

```
arr1d = S1.values # [[1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6] nan [0] [8, 9]]
print(arr1d.shape) #(5L,)
print(arr1d.ndim) # 1
```

is it possible to create a 2d array from arr1d that looks like the following

```
arr2d = np.array([[1 , 2 , 3 ] , [4 , 5 , 6] , 
[np.nan , np.nan , np.nan] , [0 , np.nan , np.nan] , [8 , 9 , np.nan]])
```

this is how the 2d array looks like

```
[[  1.   2.   3.]
 [  4.   5.   6.]
 [ nan  nan  nan]
 [  0.  nan  nan]
 [  8.   9.  nan]]

print(arr2d.ndim) # 2
print(arr2d.shape) # (5L, 3L)
```

the solution should work dynamically with any number of elements in `arr1d` this is just an example of how the data may look like

Answer (score 0):

Not claiming efficiency but this should work:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

arr2d = np.array(list(zip_longest(*np.atleast_1d(*S1), fillvalue=np.nan))).T


print(arr2d)
print(arr2d.shape)
```

Output:

```
[[  1.   2.   3.]
 [  4.   5.   6.]
 [ nan  nan  nan]
 [  0.  nan  nan]
 [  8.   9.  nan]]
(5, 3)
```